# Split a multiple JS string by new line

Tags: javascript

I have the following multi-line string that has been escaped for new-lines:

```
var types = "a\
             b\
             c\
             d";
```

I'm trying to split them by new-lines:

```
var data = types.split('\n');
```

I've had no luck with this.. How do I do this?

Comment: Well, since the new lines are escaped, it doesn't contain new line characters. You could split by spaces instead, or you have to introduce another delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting with regex:

```
types.split(/ */)
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6yx8Z/)